# Laravel 4 - Handling 404 Errors

Tags: php, frameworks, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I know that to handle 404 errors with laravel 4 is to write at app/start/global.php :

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Redirect::route('404_Error');
});
```

But actually I want to use this route:

```
Route::get('error', array(
    'as' => '404_Error',
    'uses' => 'ErrorController@get404Error'
));
```

But to stay at the same URL.

Example:

My URL right now is `localhost:8000/users/blat` (404 Error). I don't want redirect to error page. I want to see `ErrorController@get404Error` at this URL.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I can't believe there are no answers to this question. Is it really only possible to respond with a simple view instead of a controller action?

Answer (score 5):

You may try something like this:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return App::make('ErrorController')->get404Error($exception);
});
```

Your `ErrorController`:

```
class ErrorController extends BaseController {
    //...
    public function get404Error($exception)
    {
        //...
        $data = ...;
        return View::make('error_view')->with('data', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a different route it will redirect to that route, you probably will need to render your view right away, IMO it's the only way to stay where you are and not have your url changed:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return View::make('404_Error');
});
```

Comment: Actually, I have some variables in 'BaseController' that I need for the error... Another idea?

Comment: You need to show more code, there a lot of things you can do, like using View Composers, but the better we can do here without seeing your actual code is guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an instance of the `ErrorController` class and call its `get404Error` method. That way you will have the variables from your `BaseController` class too and the route will stay the same.

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    $errorController = new ErrorController();
    return $errorController->get404Error();
});
```